# Keycloak error : [org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator]

Tags: authentication, keycloak, cas

I have integrated the CAS server with Keycloak version 12.0.4. When I go to the CAS login page it redirects me to the keycloak login successfully.
After entering the valid credentials in the keycloak page, it provides an error in the cas logs which is mentioned below:

> 2021-05-12 08:51:41,865 WARN
> [org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator] -
> <Preferred token endpoint Authentication method: null not available.
> Defaulting to: private_key_jwt

Can someone tell me if I'm missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the CAS was not able to take the properties from the cas.properties. I changed the class OidcAuthenticator in the cas package to choose the method "client_secret_basic" manually. After doing this change it's working fine.